# How to create a cascading dropdown list with Angular

Tags: angular, dropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLOLZ.jpg)I'm working on a form that patients can use to make an appointment at a hospital.

- In the first dropdown patients have to select a department
- Based on the selected department, the second dropdown should display the doctors assigned to the department

[This screenshot shows my html-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyeh7.jpg)

[This screenshot shows the relevant typescript-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMboI.jpg)

When the user selects a department, `changeDept()` should be triggered. In `changeDept()` the corresponding doctor-objects should be fetched from the API and used as input of my doctor-dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I created a complete working example without using observables, since I recommend to pre-load the input-data for the doctor-dropdown. Everytime a new department is selected, `onSelect()` will be triggered and the doctors-array gets repopulated.

First the **TS-File**:

```
  departments: Department[];
  doctors: Doctor[];

  selectedDepartment: Department = null;
  selectedDoctor: Doctor = null;

  constructor(private selectService: SelectService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.departments = this.selectService.getDepartments();
    // Select the first department as default (optional):
    this.selectedDepartment = this.departments[0];
    this.onSelect(this.selectedDepartment);
  }

  onSelect(department: Department) {
    this.doctors = this.selectService
      .getDoctors()
      .filter((item) => item.departmentId == department.id);
  }
```

The **HTML-Part**:

```
<div>
  <label>Department:</label>
  <select
    [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartment"
    (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
    <option [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let department of departments" [ngValue]="department">
      {{ department.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div>
  <label>Doctor:</label>
  <select 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDoctor">  
    <option [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let doctor of doctors" [ngValue]="doctor">
      {{ doctor.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The **Service**:

```
export class SelectService {
  getDepartments() {
    return [
      new Department(1, 'Department A'),
      new Department(2, 'Department B'),
    ];
  }

  getDoctors() {
    return [
      new Doctor(1, 1, 'Dr. Khan'),
      new Doctor(2, 1, 'Dr. Peters'),
      new Doctor(3, 1, 'Dr. Keller'),
      new Doctor(4, 1, 'Dr. Suter'),
      new Doctor(5, 2, 'Ronaldo'),
      new Doctor(6, 2, 'Messi'),
      new Doctor(7, 2, 'Shakiri'),
    ];
  }
}
```

And finally the **Models**:

```
export class Department {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}
}

export class Doctor {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public departmentId: number,
    public name: string
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the doctor's dropdown with one option `Choose doctor` on the initial page load, and when the user changes the department value, you get the selected department id and call a network request to update the doctor's list with the most recent list (and show the loader and disable the department dropdown if Angular is not receiving a response).
like-

**In Component file**

```
public doctorListAsync$: BehaviorSubject<Array<[IDoc]>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);


changeDept(event:object)
{
  // here reset $doctorListAsync value
  this.doctorListAsync$.next([]);
  this.userService.showDoc(deptId).pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((docData:IDoc[])=>{
    this.doctorListAsync$.next(docData);
  })
}
```

**In html file**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(doctorListAsync$ | async).length > 0">
   <option *ngFor="let item of doctorListAsync"></option>
</ng-container>
```

Thanks